# Shell scripting: Count how many times a given character appears in a string

Tags: string, shell, sh

I need to know the number of times a given character appears in a string.

The solution should be able to run under most POSIX-compatible shell interpreters and should have as few dependencies as possible.

Comment: Your "use case" only needs the information if there is zero or (one-or-more) asterisks which would be a little bit easier to solve (SCNR)

Comment: `echo "str" | perl -e '(sub{my $q = <>; print(length($q) - 1);})->()'` or if you want to be lame `echo "hello, world" | perl -e 'print (length(<>) - 1)'`

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I have edited my question to make it clear that I need to have as few dependencies as possible. installing Perl is a lot more than using only echo, tr, test and ${# as my answer does.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shell function that only depends on `echo`, `tr`, `test` and `${#`:

```
charcount() {
  local char="$1"; shift;
  result="$(echo "$*" | tr -cd "$char")"; result=${#result};
  test $result -gt 0 && echo $result
}
```

Usage examples:

```
# charcount 'a' 'test' || echo 'char not found'
char not found

# charcount 'a' 'a test a' && echo 'found'
2
found
```

And here's a more specific solution that can only test whether the char exists in the string or not.

```
charexists() { test "$(echo "$2" | tr -cd "$1")" ;}
```